# PHP MySQL bind variable not working with REGEXP_INSTR

Tags: php, mysql, regex, bind-variables

MySQL version is `10.1.19-MariaDB`.
PHP version is `7.0.13`.

I have a table called `words2`:

```
CREATE TABLE words2 (word varchar(64));
INSERT INTO words2 VALUES ('ABSCESS'), ('ABSCISE'),('ABSCOND'),('ABSENCE');
INSERT INTO words2 VALUES ('ABSINTH'), ('ABSOLVE'), ('ABSTAIN');
INSERT INTO words2 VALUES ('ACCORDS'), ('ACCRUES'), ('ASCENDS');

SELECT * FROM words2 ORDER BY 1;

+---------+
| word    |
+---------+
| ABSCESS |
| ABSCISE |
| ABSCOND |
| ABSENCE |
| ABSINTH |
| ABSOLVE |
| ABSTAIN |
| ACCORDS |
| ACCRUES |
| ASCENDS |
+---------+
```

Now, I want to run a query that lists words starting with `'ABS'` but not containing `'O'` or `'D'`.

In the MySQL client, I run:

```
select upper(word) word 
from words2
where lower(word) like lower('abs%')
and regexp_instr(lower(word), '[od]' ) = 0
order by 1;
```

Which correctly gives:

```
+---------+
| word    |
+---------+
| ABSCESS |
| ABSCISE |
| ABSENCE |
| ABSINTH |
| ABSTAIN |
+---------+
```

In PHP, I have the following:

```
$matchchars = 'abs%';
$ignore = '[od]';

$sql = 'select upper(word) word from words w where lower(word) like ? ';
$sql .= ' and regexp_instr(lower(word), ?) = 0 ';
$sql .= ' order by upper(word)';

$stmt  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $matchchars, $ignore);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$num_rows = $result -> num_rows;
echo 'Num rows: '. $num_rows;
```

But this returns 0 rows.
If I remove the 2nd WHERE condition so that I have:

```
$matchchars = 'abs%';

$sql = 'select upper(word) word from words w where lower(word) like ? ';
$sql .= ' order by upper(word)';

$stmt  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $matchchars);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$num_rows = $result -> num_rows;
echo 'Num rows: '. $num_rows;
```

I get the expected results.

Is there a problem with using a bind variable which contains a regular expression with REGEXP_INSTR?

Comment: By the way, please upgrade to a more modern PHP version. PHP 7.0 is very old and PHP 7 is no longer supported at all. It's for your own security and benefit

Comment: Ugh, _MariaDB_ is **not** _MySQL_ - that's the whole point of it.

Comment: Use a case_insensitive (..._ci) collation, then get rid of all the `UPPER()s` and `LOWER()s`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was a bug in my PHP that was slightly different to the snippet above which runs perfectly. I had got the variable name in the `bind_param('ss', $matchchars, $ignore);` wrong.

Comment: Then you should get an uninitialized variable notice.